# Certificate path unreachable for SSL in Java/Clojure

Tags: java, validation, security, ssl, clojure

I'm using `http-kit` in Clojure and when accessing an `https://` page I get `unable to find valid certification path to requested target`:

```
:cause unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 :via
 [{:type javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
   :message General SSLEngine problem
   :at [sun.security.ssl.Handshaker checkThrown Handshaker.java 1375]}
  {:type javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
   :message General SSLEngine problem
   :at [sun.security.ssl.Alerts getSSLException Alerts.java 192]}
  {:type sun.security.validator.ValidatorException
   :message PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBui
lderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   :at [sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator doBuild PKIXValidator.java 387]}
  {:type sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException
   :message unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   :at [sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder build SunCertPathBuilder.j
ava 145]}]
```

I tried to find a simple solution, and I see that there are recommendations to solve it programatically. Isn't there some simple way, I just want to get a web page. I even do not care about the security in this case. Can I make java to relax this?

Thanks for suggestions..

Comment: Which https page are you trying to access?

Comment: @DanielCompton, it's https://www.gombaszog.sk/

Comment: I cannot provide any code (and hence won't post this as an answer), but there's a recent article on the exact topic of [https requests with client certificates in Clojure](https://www.lvh.io/posts/https-requests-with-client-certificates-in-clojure.html) that might or might be of help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http/get takes an "insecure?" option:

```
@(http/get "http://gombaszog.sk" {:insecure? true})
```

Comment: this helped, thanks, found also how to fix certificates correctly in java, and how to make it simpler in Clojure. https://github.com/aphyr/less-awful-ssl and https://www.lvh.io/posts/https-requests-with-client-certificates-in-clojure.html for cases when `{:insecure? true}` is not a way.